# xPath Help - Selecting a specific word within a string

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping

I am looking to extract a part of a string using xPath.

Full string -

> Informational (nonfiction), 1,303 words, Level S (Grade 3)

HTML code:

```
<div class="bookInfo">
    Informational (nonfiction),
1,303 words,
Level S  (Grade 3)
</div>
```

I am looking to extract just the number of words from these strings, i.e. - `1,303 words` in this case

The xPath of this string looks like

```
//*[@id="contentarea-inner"]/div[3]/div[2]/div
```

Webpage in question - https://www.readinga-z.com/books/leveled-books/book/?id=820

Please advise on how I can modify the xPath so as to extract only the number of words from the page. I have several thousand pages to get this info from

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need both xpath and regex:

1. Get the text of the div node by xPath (see Shubham Jain's code)
2. Apply regex to the text; for example. this: `\s[,\d]+(?= words)`. See the [regex's work](https://regex101.com/r/aW2vP1/1) on the text node.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same using split function in java

Use the code:-

```
String text= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentarea-inner']/div[3]/div[2]/div")).getText();
String count1 = text.split(",")[1];
String count2 = text.split(",")[2];
String count = count1 + count2;
System.out.println(count);
```

Please get back to me if still facing any issue :)

Comment: Thanks Subham - could you please let me know the xPath by which I could get just the no.of words on that string. I need to use the xPath on an application to extract the no. of words of these pages. I can't use the Java code for this. Thanks

Comment: @ShubhamJain, since you use `test.split(',')` the result might be wrong because the text is like this `...,
1,303 words,` with comma inside the number!

Comment: @IgorSavinkin -> yes you are absolute right... thanx for pointing out .. I have made changes accordingly

Comment: @pb_ng -> I afraid that there is no mechanism to extract/return a particular String using xpath ...

Comment: @pb_ng, you are right: *there is no mechanism to extract/return a particular String using xpath* - xPath is only for traversing DOM nodes.